# Angular subscriptions in reduxless architecture

Tags: angular

I have an old angular 6 application without flux/redux.
In ngOnInit i can get initial data for the component, there i use takeUntil(unsubscribe), and everything is clear.

My question is - how can i correctly process, for example, button click that has to send some other request to server, or search field that sends request for some filtered data?

My concern is that if i place something like this in event handler:

```
this.service.get({parametes}).pipe(takeUntil(unsubscribe)).subscribe((data)=> {...})
```

then, on each click or filter change it will create one more subscription that would in the end create a memory leak.

Could anybody please advice how to avoid new subscription creation?

Is creating a new subscription upon each event the right approach at all?

(I understand that using effects solves the problem, but what about correct reduxless approach?)

Comment: You can use `toPromise`

Comment: Is there any benefit of using this in regards of avoiding extra subscriptions? Or this is just to use async/await syntax?

Comment: You don't need to clean up subscriptions (unsubscribe/takeUntil)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really avoid making requests to the BE so you'll end up with subscription/promise any time you need filterer data. Don't worry that much about HTTP request, they get automatically unsubscribed when they complete. If you want to be sure, that they're destroyed, you can use `takeUntil` as you do, or simply use `take` and specify after how many emissions you want to complete the subscription. In the case below after one emission it'll get unsubscribed.

```
this.service.get({parametes}).pipe(take(1)).subscribe((data)=> {...})
```

But I think in your case you should focus more on disabling/filtering clicks on the button while the get request is processed.

```
// This can help when you event handler is also some observable
clickEvent.pipe(debounceTime(500)).subscribe(() => getData());

// Or this when it's a "classic" function called on button click
this.wasClicked = true
this.service.get({parametes})
  .pipe(take(1))
  .subscribe((data)=> {
    this.wasClicked = false
  })
```